# GenericTraversableTemplate::flatten. What kind of magic does it do?

Tags: scala, collections, flatten

I'm trying to understand what kind of magic the `flatten` method does. Here is an example form [this article](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/collection-scala-flatmap-examples-map-flatten)

```
def toInt(s: String): Option[Int] = {
    try {
        Some(Integer.parseInt(s.trim))
    } catch {
        // catch Exception to catch null 's'
        case e: Exception => None
    }
}

scala> val strings = Seq("1", "2", "foo", "3", "bar")
strings: Seq[java.lang.String] = List(1, 2, foo, 3, bar)

scala> strings.map(toInt)
res0: Seq[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), Some(2), None, Some(3), None)

scala> val flattenResult = mapResult.flatten
flattenResult: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Wow. It looks like some miracle. How does the `flatten` method know that we should not add `None`s to the resulting collection. It's not obvious form its implementation at all:

```
def flatten[B](implicit asTraversable: A => /*<:<!!!*/ GenTraversableOnce[B]): CC[B] = {
    val b = genericBuilder[B]
    for (xs <- sequential)
      b ++= asTraversable(xs).seq
    b.result()
  }
```

Couldn't you explain the sense of it... I mean what does it do in general? Maybe it does know, that `None` is a ***monadic value*** and use some of its "monadic" methods. But it's just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see that `flatten` can be called on collections which contain values convertible to `GenTraversableOnce`:

```
def flatten[B](implicit asTraversable: A => GenTraversableOnce[B]): CC[B]
```

Since in `Option` [companion object](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L17) exists an implicit conversion to `Iterable`, it should be eligible to be `flatten`-ed(`Iterable` is subtype of `GenTraversableOnce`).

It converts `Option` to `List`, its implementation is obvious..

Please correct me if I'm wrong, I am too overwhelmed with Scala's collections implementation...

Comment: My only correction is `s/it's/its/`. Also, I'm not sure anything is obvious. The other answer also shows the code, which also isn't obvious. It's non-obvious all the way down.

Comment: Very interesting. I could not imagine that it was an implicit conversion all about.

Answer (score 2):

Flatten method receives implicitly a method which able to take an A (Option in our case) and convert it to GenTraversableOnce.

Option object has an implicit method defined in it:

```
implicit def option2Iterable[A](xo: Option[A]): Iterable[A] = xo.toList
```

And toList check if the object is empty before returning an Iterable:

```
def toList: List[A] =
    if (isEmpty) List() else new ::(this.get, Nil)
```

Meaning we will get an empty list when applying option2Iterable on None.

So the line:

```
b ++= asTraversable(xs).seq
```

Is actually adding an empty seq to b when performed on None or a list with the value of the Some in case of a Some.

And this is why you can't see None / Some object in your flatten output, but only the values of the Some objects.

Comment: I would have said, `And this, Virginia, is why you can't see None.` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes,_Virginia,_there_is_a_Santa_Claus